# How to count occurrence of each sentence in Excel in this specific case?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, excel-2016, ms-access-2016

The challenge here is the sentence is not split by cell. They are in the same column, but they might appear in the same cell. One sentence per line.

[image]

I need to count the occurrence of each sentence, for example, occurrence of "The cat is pink" is 2 and occurrence of "The dog is green" is 1.

I can also do Access 2016 if needed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for the number of occurrences of some sentences, or all of them? If the latter, do you have a list of unique sentences? What determines a new sentence within a cell, a carriage return?

Comment: I am looking for the number of occurrences of all of them. I do not have a list of unique sentences. A carriage return determines a new sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you can split multi-sentence cells into multiple cells)

1) Split the cells with multiple sentences, you should be able to adapt [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851951/split-text-in-cells-at-line-breaks) to do this.

2) Make a copy of the column (elsewhere on the same sheet or in another sheet -- used column B in the same sheet),

3) Remove duplicate values for the copied column

4) Next to the column use the following array formula:

```
{=SUM(LEN(A$1:A$5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1:A$5,B1,"")))/LEN(B1)}
```

(press `<CTRL><SHIFT><ENTER>` when entering an array formula)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sort column A --> a-z then
add a header to column A (to use in subtotals)
then from the Data tab,  use "subtotals" using "count" as the function

Comment: Good to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**`=COUNTIF(A:A,"*Cat is Yellow*")`**

The same formula can be applied for all the rows.